# Mvvmcross tableviewcell binding error

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I wrote a mvvmcross touch sample app, basically a rip of the CustomerManagement tutorial.
I have one customer in my CustomersListViewModel.

When I run the app I get the following error in the output (look at the end of this post).

If I load a bunch of unrequired plugins in my setup class, the error goes away.  Could this be a timing issue?

You can find the code for the project at https://github.com/patbonecrusher/MvxTableViewSampleApp.git

```
Starting iOS simulator 6.1
Launching application
Application launched. PID = 95621
Loaded assembly: /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.dll [External]
Thread started:  #2
Loaded assembly: /Volumes/dagon/Users/pat/Projects/learning-sandbox/MvxBindingTableTest/MvxBindingTableTest/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/MvxBindingTableTest.exe
Loaded assembly: /Volumes/dagon/Users/pat/Projects/learning-sandbox/MvxBindingTableTest/MvvmCross-    Binaries/XS-iOS-Mac/bin/Release/Mvx/Touch/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Volumes/dagon/Users/pat/Projects/learning-sandbox/MvxBindingTableTest/MvvmCross-Binaries/XS-iOS-Mac/bin/Release/Mvx/Touch/Cirrious.MvvmCross.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Volumes/dagon/Users/pat/Projects/learning-sandbox/MvxBindingTableTest/MvvmCross-Binaries/XS-iOS-Mac/bin/Release/Mvx/Touch/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Dialog.Touch.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Volumes/dagon/Users/pat/Projects/learning-sandbox/MvxBindingTableTest/MvvmCross-Binaries/XS-iOS-Mac/bin/Release/Mvx/Touch/Cirrious.CrossCore.Touch.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Volumes/dagon/Users/pat/Projects/learning-sandbox/MvxBindingTableTest/MvvmCross-Binaries/XS-iOS-Mac/bin/Release/Mvx/Touch/Cirrious.CrossCore.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Volumes/dagon/Users/pat/Projects/learning-sandbox/MvxBindingTableTest/MvvmCross-Binaries/XS-iOS-Mac/bin/Release/Mvx/Touch/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Volumes/dagon/Users/pat/Projects/learning-sandbox/MvxBindingTableTest/MvvmCross-Binaries/XS-iOS-Mac/bin/Release/Mvx/Touch/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Volumes/dagon/Users/pat/Projects/learning-sandbox/MvxBindingTableTest/MvxBindingTableTest.Core/bin/Debug/MvxBindingTableTest.Core.dll
Loaded assembly: /Volumes/dagon/Users/pat/Projects/learning-sandbox/MvxBindingTableTest/MvvmCross-Binaries/XS-iOS-Mac/bin/Release/Mvx/Touch/CrossUI.Touch.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Volumes/dagon/Users/pat/Projects/learning-sandbox/MvxBindingTableTest/MvvmCross-Binaries/XS-iOS-Mac/bin/Release/Mvx/Touch/CrossUI.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Volumes/dagon/Users/pat/Projects/learning-sandbox/MvxBindingTableTest/MvvmCross-Binaries/XS-iOS-Mac/bin/Release/Mvx/Touch/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.File.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Volumes/dagon/Users/pat/Projects/learning-sandbox/MvxBindingTableTest/MvvmCross-Binaries/XS-iOS-Mac/bin/Release/Mvx/Touch/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.ResourceLoader.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/Mono.Security.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Xml.dll [External]
2013-05-14 10:47:47.266 MvxBindingTableTest[95621:c07] mvx: Diagnostic:   0.00 Setup: PlatformServices start
2013-05-14 10:47:47.277 MvxBindingTableTest[95621:c07] mvx: Diagnostic:   0.05 Setup: Bootstrap actions
2013-05-14 10:47:47.287 MvxBindingTableTest[95621:c07] mvx: Diagnostic:   0.06 Setup: StringToTypeParser start
2013-05-14 10:47:47.291 MvxBindingTableTest[95621:c07] mvx: Diagnostic:   0.06 Setup: ViewModelFramework start
2013-05-14 10:47:47.293 MvxBindingTableTest[95621:c07] mvx: Diagnostic:   0.06 Setup: PluginManagerFramework start
2013-05-14 10:47:47.295 MvxBindingTableTest[95621:c07] mvx: Diagnostic:   0.07 Setup: App start
2013-05-14 10:47:47.296 MvxBindingTableTest[95621:c07] mvx: Diagnostic:   0.07 Setup:   ViewModelTypeFinder start
2013-05-14 10:47:47.297 MvxBindingTableTest[95621:c07] mvx: Diagnostic:   0.07 Setup: ViewsContainer start
2013-05-14 10:47:47.299 MvxBindingTableTest[95621:c07] mvx: Diagnostic:   0.07 Setup: ViewDispatcher start
2013-05-14 10:47:47.299 MvxBindingTableTest[95621:c07] mvx: Diagnostic:   0.07 Setup: Views start
2013-05-14 10:47:47.311 MvxBindingTableTest[95621:c07] mvx: Diagnostic:   0.08 Setup: CommandCollectionBuilder start
2013-05-14 10:47:47.312 MvxBindingTableTest[95621:c07] mvx: Diagnostic:   0.08 Setup: NavigationSerializer start
2013-05-14 10:47:47.313 MvxBindingTableTest[95621:c07] mvx: Diagnostic:   0.08 Setup: LastChance start
2013-05-14 10:47:47.326 MvxBindingTableTest[95621:c07] mvx: Diagnostic:   0.10 Setup: Secondary end
2013-05-14 10:47:47.327 MvxBindingTableTest[95621:c07] mvx: Diagnostic:   0.10 Showing ViewModel CustomerListViewModel
2013-05-14 10:47:47.330 MvxBindingTableTest[95621:c07] TouchNavigation: Diagnostic:   0.10 Navigate requested
2013-05-14 10:47:47.405 MvxBindingTableTest[95621:c07] MvxBind: Error:   0.18 MvxBind
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the full error log and for the github repro.

The blank trace error message is confusing me...

But I'm guessing that this error is caused by the fact that our standard table view cell wrapper creates an imageloader by default - see https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch/Views/MvxStandardTableViewCell.cs#L57

I'm guessing that the trace is somehow coming from https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding/Views/MvxBaseImageViewLoader.cs#L30

This imageloader uses the DownloadCache plugin which in turn uses the File plugin. (It further needs a text serializer like the JSON plugin if you want it to persist images on disk more permanently).

If you don't want images in your app - so don't want those plugins - then it doesn't look like you can avoid this problem and continue using the standard cell without changing the source.

If you wanted to workaround this problem:

1 you could create your own Standard Table cell wrapper (based on https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch/Views/MvxStandardTableViewCell.cs#L57)
2 you could use create a custom cell.
3 you could register a dummy/empty service to satisfy `IMvxImageHelper<UIImage>` - this would work but I don't really like it as a solution.

If you think this is a serious problem we should provide a core fix for, please do log it as an issue on github/slodge/mvvmcross.

In real apps I don't tend to use the Standard cells and I also tend to always need the downloadcache and file plugin - so I don't personally come across this as a common problem in my work.

Comment: Thanks Stuart! That helps... I can work around that issue.. No big deal to load the plugin... Just wanted to make sure I wasn't crazy! :D